# space utilization

Tags: disk-usage

I need to show space utilisation on the system, and find the largest 3 files on /home (or any other folder)

I've been using 2 different command lines

```
df -m -a -h
df -m -h /home
```

I still can't manage to get it to show me only the 3 largest files on that folder

Answer (score 3):

For top 3 files, with GNU `find`, and assuming no filename contain newline characters:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f -printf "%s %p\n" |sort -nr |head -3
```

That gives the 3 largest files in term of file size. For disk usage instead, replace `%s` with `%b`.

Answer (score 0):

For top 3 files and folders in the current directory.
It will show you the largest files and folders.

```
du -sm ./* 2>/dev/null | sort -n -r | head -n 3
```

If you really insist on files only, then X Tian's solution is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using modern GNU versions of `du` and `sort`, this will show you the sizes:

```
$ du -hs * | sort -hr
53G         projects
21G         Desktop
7.2G        VirtualBox VMs
3.7G        db
3.3G        SparkleShare
2.2G        Dropbox
272M        apps
47M         incoming
14M         bin
8.6M        parking_lot
5.7M        rpmbuild
76K         task.ref.pdf
68K         vimdir.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh`, you can see the 3 largest files (in terms of size, not disk usage) with:

```
ls -ldh -- *(DOL[1,3])
```

To check for disk usage, you'd need to define a sort order like:

```
zmodload zsh/stat
sdu() stat -A REPLY +block -- $REPLY
```

And use as:

```
ls -ldh -- *(DnO+sdu[1,3])
```

If you want to search for the largest file anywhere including subdirectories, change the `*` above to `**/*`.